# How do i calculate the size of a tag field?

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I'm revising for an exam and i've came across a question that I have no idea how to do, i've looked through my notes and cant seem to find anything on it, can anyone help me?

Given a 64KB cache that contains 1024 blocks with 64 bytes per block, what is the size of the tag field for a 32-bit architecture?

The question is only worth 1 mark so i cant imagine the answer is too hard, but i cant seem to find anthing on it.

Comment: See the wiki article on [CPU Cache Entry Structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_entry_structure), it gives you the maths to figure out the size of the tag field given the other parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need **32** bits for the address. You need **6** bits for the offset within a block. You need **10** bits to identify one of the 1,024 possible blocks in the cache. That's **16** bits in total. Therefore the tag needs to be **32** bits - **16** bits = **16** bits.

I recommend following the link that aruisdante provided and look at how to calculate this yourself.